# How can I make my nodeJS container connect with my mongoDB container?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 fairly simple Docker containers, 1 containing a NodeJS application, the other one is just a MongoDB container.

**Dockerfile.nodeJS**

```
FROM node:boron

ENV NODE_ENV production

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /node/api-server
WORKDIR /node/api-server

# Install app dependencies
COPY /app-dir/package.json /node/api-server/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY /app-dir /node/api-server

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "." ]
```

**Dockerfile.mongodb**

```
FROM mongo:3.4.4

# Create database storage directory
VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["mongod"]

EXPOSE 27017
```

They both work independently from each other, but when I create 2 separate containers of it, they won't communicate with each other anymore (Why?). Online there are a lot of tutorials about doing it [with](http://blog.mpayetta.com/node.js/docker/mongodb/2016/09/04/dockerizing-node-mongo-app/) or [without](http://www.ifdattic.com/how-to-mongodb-nodejs-docker/) docker-compose. But they all use `--link`. Which is [a deprecated legacy feature of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). So I don't want to go that path. What is the way to go in 2017, to make this connection between 2 docker containers?

Comment: The Docker documentation has ["Communication between containers"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communication-between-containers) as a topic within the larger topic of networking in general.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a specific network

`docker create network -d overlay boron_mongo`

and then you launch both containers with such a command

`docker run --network=boron_mongo...`

extract from

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

The preferred way is to use docker-compose

Have a look at

Configuring the default network

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks